# How to save session into phone?

Tags: android, facebook, session, sharedpreferences

Currently, my session always null, Suppose bundle will not null.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_scene);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splashbg);
    rLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_bg);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) {
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SplashScene.this)
                .setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        updateView();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // disable back button by overriding it
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            GlobalFunction.token = session.getAccessToken();
            IsExistMember checkmember = new IsExistMember();
            checkmember.execute();
        }
    }
}

private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()
            && session.getState() != SessionState.OPENING) {
        OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(this)
                .setCallback(statusCallback);
        List<String> permission = new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("email");
        open.setPermissions(permission);
        session.openForRead(open.setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        // Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScene.this, WelcomeScene.class);
        // startActivity(intent);
        // finish();
    }

}
```

How do I keep the session into phone and when next time run this apps no need to create new session.

I was checking the session in this `Activity`. If exist then proceed else go other Activity to sign in with facebook and save the bundle into phone.

Based on the tutorial, it was taught to do everything with an `Activity` but I want do separately in different `Activity`.

There is something like `sharedpreference`, I think is it same as iOS `appdelegate`?

Comment: Why dont you use Shared Preferences.?

Answer (score 0):

use `onRestoreInstanceState` and `onSaveInstanceState` callbacks to store your values (state variables) and restoring them on the next launch.

To have a good idea of how these work, look android activity life cycle.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

You always need to create a new Session. However, if the user has previously authorized your app, then the sessionState will be CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED, and when you call openForRead, there's no user interaction (it just silently opens with the saved credentials).

Why do you NOT want to create a new instance of Session?